# color swatches for products not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, category-listing

all the settings and attributes are proper yet the color swatches not working.
kindly help !!
product link : http://www.i-ranu.com/yellow-plain-western-crepe-dresse-for-girls.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting jQuery undefined Error. I think its not working because JS is broken.

[image]

Comment: thanks for guidance sir, i found its because of a extension after uninstalling the same its working fine !